# windows 10 not detecting other disk partions

Tags: windows, disk

I had Ubuntu 16.04 And now installed windows 10 and dual booted it , and now both Ubuntu and windows are running fine but windows is not detecting other disk drives

Answer (score 7):

That's to be expected.

Windows has no support for UNIX/Linux filesystems (`ext4` in this case).

There is at least one program (for example, `etx2fsd`) that can be installed on Windows in order to read/write `ext2/3/4` partitions, but I strongly recommend against trying it.

If you need to share data between the two OSes, then create a separate NTFS partition or use a cloud service.

There are no good reasons to be accessing the system partition of one OS from another in dual boot. It's usually a recipe for disaster.